# OnError event not returning control and a blank page is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, onerror

I'm handling exceptions at page level the following way

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
     Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

     Master.Message = ex.Message;
     Server.ClearError();

     base.OnError(e);
}
```

After executing this code I get a blank page and the function does not return control

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Handle errors in global.asax.  Here 1) set your error display 2) decide whether or not to throw the error / let it bubble up to the global.asax code.